# Is every xvalue an rvalue?

Tags: c++, value-categories

The standard denotes an xvalue as a glvalue whose resources can be reused. It also defines an rvalue as either an xvalue or a prvalue. And a prvalue is defined as an expression that either initializes an object, computes the value of an operand of an operator or of an expression of type cv void.
To me right now this concludes the following: Every xvalue is a glvalue but since an rvalue can be either a prvalue(no xvalues are prvalues) or an xvalue and the definition of prvalues does not rule xvalues out of being an rvalue these definitions do not clarify that an xvalue has to be an rvalue.
Is every xvalue a glvalue as well as an rvalue?

I tried to understand the standard but couldnt conclude on myself whether my statement is true.

Comment: There is a nice diagram in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3601748/7691729).

Comment: Bjarne Stroustrup has a nice [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38169963/4641116), and how the value categories relate to **identity** and **movability**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. There are three mutually exclusive categories: lvalues, xvalues, and prvalues.

lvalues and xvalues together are called glvalues.

prvalues and xvalues together are called rvalues.

Comment: But whats the reasoning: From where in the standard follows this?

Comment: @ELIAS You said it yourself: *"It also defines an rvalue as either an xvalue or a prvalue"* (standard says the same thing: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval), I don't understand what else you need here.

Comment: But from this it follows that an rvalue is either an xvalue or a prvalue. So not all rvalues are xvalues hence we cant conclude that all xvalues must be rvalues.

Comment: @ELIAS *"So not all rvalues are xvalues"* Correct. *"hence we cant conclude that all xvalues must be rvalues"* Wrong. It's like saying "not all creatures that can swim are fishes, hence not all fishes can swim", which is a logical error. xvalues are a subset of rvalues. Fishes are a subset of the things that can swim.

Comment: I get that, thanks for sticking with me. But we also cant conclude that every fish can swim. Where in the standard does it say or from what can we conclude that all xvalues must be also rvalues?

Comment: @ELIAS Your quote [*"An rvalue is a prvalue or an xvalue."*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#1.5) literally means that any prvalue is rvalue and any xvalue is rvalue, and something that's neither a prvalue nor xvalue is not rvalue.

Comment: @ELIAS I recommend this (and to do some practice) https://www.academia.edu/7629446/Lewis_Carrolls_logic

Comment: Thx for sticking with me, my bad.

Comment: @ELIAS No worries, I hope it'll click for you. :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat 'Your quote "An rvalue is a prvalue or an xvalue." literally means that any prvalue is rvalue and any xvalue is rvalue, and something that's neither a prvalue nor xvalue is not rvalue.' Only the latter is true. From e ∈ R ⇒ (e ∈ PR ∨ e ∈ X) only the contraposition (e ∉ PR ∧ e ∉ X) ⇒ e ∉ R can be concluded. It does not imply e ∈ X ⇒ e ∈ R.

Comment: @Hajny It's not e ∈ R ⇒ (e ∈ PR ∨ e ∈ X), but rather e ∈ R ≡ (e ∈ PR ∨ e ∈ X).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'd have to agree with Hajny. I don't see where 'An rvalue is a prvalue or an xvalue' would imply that all x- and prvalues must be an rvalue.

Comment: @ELIAS I don't know what else to say to you. This depends on how you understand "An rvalue is a prvalue or an xvalue". I see at least two possible meanings: It's either an exhaustive definition of rvalues ("every rvalue is either a prvalue or xvalue, and conversely every prvalue or xvalue is a prvalue", this what I keep repeating to you) or just a general statement about rvalues ("some prvalues and xvalues are rvalues, and nothing else can be an rvalue", which is the meaning you insist on).

Comment: @ELIAS If the latter is true, then there must be some other definition of "rvalue" elsewhere, because otherwise we would have no way to know what subset of prvalues&xvalues are rvalues. There's no such "other definition" in the standard, so we have to assume the former meaning (this sentence being the exhaustive definition).